# Is there a way to ensure that threads are assigned to a specified set of objects?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

We are working on an application where a set of objects can be affected by receiving messages from 3 different sources. Each message (from any of the sources) has a single object as its target. Each message receiver will be running on its own thread.

We want the processing of the messages (after receiving), to be as high-speed as possible, so the message processing against the target objects will be done with another thread from a thread pool. The processing of the message will take longer than the reading/receiving of the messages from the senders.

I am thinking that it will be faster if each thread from the pool is dedicated only to a particular set of objects, for example:

```
Thread1 -> objects named A-L
Thread2 -> objects named M-Z
```

with each set of objects (or Thread) having a dedicated queue of messages to pending being processed.

My assumption is that if the only thread synchronization needed is between each receiving thread and one processing thread, for the duration of time that it needs to put the message on a blocking queue, that it will be faster than randomly assigning worker threads to process the messages (in which case there might be 2 different threads with messages for the same object).

My question is really 2 parts:

1. Do people agree with the assumption that dedicating worker threads
       to a particular set of objects is a better/faster approach?
2. Assuming this is a better approach, do the existing Java ThreadPool
       classes have a way to support this?  Or does it require us coding
       our own ThreadPool implementation?

Thanks for any advice that you can offer.

Comment: So the trick is that you can't have 2 messages with the same target object being processed by different threads at the same time?

Comment: Have you done any tests to see if this is a problem to begin with?

Comment: @Gray: yes - each of the 2 messages for the same target object will update the state of the target object, and also potentially trigger generating another message.  The 2 messages are *definitely not* allowed to update the object concurrently (i.e. without synchronization) because that could cause the object's state to be inconsistent (as seen by concurrent threads).

Comment: @MattiLyra: From other similar applications performance, we know that there is in imbalance between receiving latency to processing latency. Regarding whether concurrent threads would see inconsistent state (if not synchronized or dedicated as I suggested), I am not 100% sure - but it is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: But if the target objects have to be synchronized, what is the point of the dividing up of the object sets?  Why separate the objects into A-L M-Z?

Comment: @Gray: You're asking a good question. To me, it is a question of where the synchronization points are. We are starting from a point where each of the message receivers are on their own threads. If 2 messages arrive simultaneously for same object, and message is handed directly 2 worker threads, then 1 worker thread is blocked for the entire time it takes the other thread to process. If each receiver thread simply puts onto a blocking queue, each receiver is blocked only for time to put on queue. And the dedicated thread is not blocked by any other thread (unless queue limit is reached).

Comment: I've moved my last comment out to an answer @Sam.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [Is] dedicating worker threads to a particular set of objects is a better/faster approach?

I assume the overall goals is to trying to maximize the concurrent processing of these inbound messages.  You have receivers from the 3 sources, that need to put the messages in a pool that will be optimally handled.  Because messages from any of the 3 sources may deal with the same target object which *cannot* be processed simultaneously, you want someway to divide up your messages so they can be processed concurrently but only if they are guaranteed to not refer to the same target object.

I would implement the `hashCode()` method on your target object (maybe just `name.hashCode()`) and then use the value to put the objects into an array of `BlockingQueue`s, each with a single thread consuming them.  Using an array of `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` would be fine.  Mod the hash value mode by the number of queues and put it in that queue.  You will need to pre-define the number of processors to maximum.  Depends on how CPU intensive the processing is.

So something like the following code should work:

```
 private static final int NUM_PROCESSING_QUEUES = 6;
 ...
 ExecutorService[] pools = new ExecutorService[NUM_PROCESSING_QUEUES];
 for (int i = 0; i < pools.length; i++) {
    pools[i] = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
 }
 ...
 // receiver loop:
 while (true) {
    Message message = receiveMessage();
    int hash = Math.abs(message.hashCode());
    // put each message in the appropriate pool based on its hash
    // this assumes message is runnable
    pools[hash % pools.length].submit(message);
 }
```

One of the benefits of this mechanism is that you may be able to limit the synchronization about the target objects.  You *know* that the same target object will only be updated by a single thread.

> Do people agree with the assumption that dedicating worker threads to a particular set of objects is a better/faster approach?

Yes.  That seems the right way to get optimal concurrency.

> Assuming this is a better approach, do the existing Java ThreadPool classes have a way to support this? Or does it require us coding our own ThreadPool implementation?

I don't know of any thread-pool which accomplishes this.  I would *not* write your own implementation however.  Just use them like the code outlines above.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code. I'll give this a try, and let you know how it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please keep in mind that `.hashCode()` may return a negative integer. For safety use: `Math.abs(hash)`.

Comment: Thanks @RubenErnst.  I've fixed my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In general, approaches like this are a bad idea. It falls under the "[don't optimize early](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)" mantra.

Further, if implemented your idea may *harm* your performance, not help it. One simple example of where it wouldn't work well is if you suddenly got a lot of requests on one type - the other worker thread would be idle.

The best approach is to use a standard producer-consumer pattern and tune the number of consumer threads by system testing under various loads - ideally by feeding in a recording of real-life transactions.

The "go to" framework for these situation are classes from the [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. I recommend using a [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) (proably an [`ArrayBlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html)) with an [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) created from one of the [`Executors`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) factory methods, probably [`newCachedThreadPool()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool%28%29).

Once you have implemented and system tested that, if you find proven performance problems, then analyse your system, find the bottleneck and fix it.

The reason you shouldn't optimize early is that most times the problems are not where you expect them to be

Comment: I am considering how to build this in a thread neutral way, so that the threading algorithm could be changed. So if I can think of a way to abstract the handoff of messages behind some interface, then maybe I could leave these decisions until we are performance testing.

Comment: The `Executors` class offers several factory methods, some configurable, and `ExecutorService` is configurable itself so you can always write your own implementation. It's a good place to start and a great API to learn.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach: I would recommend using an existing framework, such as [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/) for this.  Trying to invent your own messaging framework can be a challenge.  If you are trying to add value with your own framework, that's one thing.  If you simply need one to accomplish your goals, that's another.  These frameworks have come up with many options for optimal message delivery and would be worth considering.

Comment: Actually, we aren't inventing our own framework, we are integrating with some external systems which are sending messages via TCP. I think sticking an MQ solution as a middleware layer will definitely add latency and complexity.

Answer (score 0):

My answers are:

- 1 - yes
- 2 -

  - a) No
  - b) you don't need to

Some explanations:

- you want one task to distribute messages to different queues according to some algorithm,
- You want one task per message queue to pull messages from its assigned queue and process them.

I don't think that these premises are contradicting the purpose of the ThreadPool, which is just about associating tasks to threads. In this model though, the Threadpool would associate threads to tasks only once, and then threads would keep running to poll their input message queue.

The friction spots of the threads should be the intermediate messages queues, and perhaps other resources related to the processing of these messages. Following your explanations, I suppose that you plan to reduce the second kind to a minimum by cleverly partitioning the message processing to the tasks. Each queue should only be accessed by the partitioning task and the processing task associated to the queue, so it should be minimal.

Comment: Could you please point me to some sample code, or which Java ThreadPool/ExecutorService would make it easy to do this?

Comment: There wouldn't be anything particularly difficult in the setup. One just need to define the tasks as infinite loops polling their queue, and acting on new messages. The threadpool would start them once, and let them run on their own.

Comment: I can't provide you a sample application yet (I am not on my computer).

Comment: If you have `n` message partitions, then you only need `n+1` threads, so a fixedThreadPool would do.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to provide a special BlockingQueue for ThreadPoolExecutor. The queue remembers which type of message is being processed by which thread, so that it can withhold all messages of the same type.

```
MyQueue

    ownership relation of thread - msgType 

    take/poll()

        if current thread owns msg type X
            if there is a message of type X
                return that message
            else
                give up ownership

        // current thread does not own any message type
        if there is a messsage of type Y, Y is not owned by any thread
            current thread owns Y
            return that message

        // there's no message belonging to an unowned type
        wait then retry
```