# Does Java have an indexable multi-queue thread pool?

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, threadpool

Is there a Java class such that:

1. Executable tasks can be added via an id, where all tasks with the same id are guaranteed to never run concurrently
2. The number of threads can be limited to a fixed amount

A naive solution of a Map would easily solve (1), but it would be difficult to manage (2). Similarly, all thread pooling classes that I know of will pull from a single queue, meaning (1) is not guaranteed.

Solutions involving external libraries are welcome.

Comment: @Makky, I had been specifically looking at Spring TaskExecutor

Comment: @downvoters, why is this a bad question? This is not a "plz give me teh code" question, and seems to me that it would be a fairly common use case for multi-threading, and googling doesn't yield any obvious results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't find something that does this out of the box, it shouldn't be hard to roll your own. One thing you could do is to wrap each task in a simple class that reads on a queue unique per id, e.g.:

```
public static class SerialCaller<T> implements Callable<T> {
    private final BlockingQueue<Caller<T>> delegates;

    public SerialCaller(BLockingQueue<Caller<T>> delegates) {
        this.delegates = delegates;
    }

    public T call() throws Exception {
        return delegates.take().call();
    }
}
```

It should be easy to maintain a map of ids to queues for submitting tasks. That satisfies condition (1), and then you can look for simple solutions to condition (2), such as [Executors. newFixedThreadPool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29)

Comment: Your initial proposal seemed lighter and easier to implement - any reason for the change?

Comment: @assylias I realized it could be a big bottleneck. Let's say your thread pool is also limited to N threads, and you've got N tasks under id A, as well as some number under id B and C. By an unfortunate coincidence, all of A's tasks get scheduled. That means N-1 threads are blocked -- and not executing tasks for B or C.

Comment: could you please complete this answer by adding source code about maping ids to queues and submit and polling tasks ?

Answer (score 4):

For each id, you need a SerialExecutor, described in the documentation of [java.util.concurrent.Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html). All serial executors delegate work to a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) with given corePoolSize.

Opimized version of SerialExecutor can be found at [my code samples](https://github.com/akaigoro/CodeSamples/blob/master/src/main/java/actor/serialexec/SerialExecutor.java).

Comment: This is a hidden gem in the Java documentation! SerialExecutor effectively implements a multiqueue thread pool, but they don't really make that explicit.

Comment: @Alexei Kaigorodov, after you've re-arranged your github repo, some of your links in your older answers end up with 404 - I've run into 2 different cases since yesterday. I'm guessing the one referred here is [this file](https://github.com/akaigoro/CodeSamples/blob/master/src/main/java/actor/serialexec/SerialExecutor.java), but please try to fix them when you have the chance. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think that the simplest solution is to just have a separate queue for each index and a separate executor (with one thread) for each queue.

The only thing you could achieve with a more complex solution would be to use fewer threads, but if the number of indexes is small and bounded that's probably not worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is such a library now: https://github.com/jano7/executor

```java
int maxTasks = 10;
ExecutorService underlyingExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxTasks);
KeySequentialBoundedExecutor executor = new KeySequentialBoundedExecutor(maxTasks, underlyingExecutor);

Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // do something
    }
};

executor.execute(new KeyRunnable<>("ID-1", task)); // execute the task by the underlying executor
executor.execute(new KeyRunnable<>("ID-2", task)); // execution is not blocked by the task for ID-1
executor.execute(new KeyRunnable<>("ID-1", task)); // execution starts when the previous task for ID-1 completes
```