# Java, divide incoming work uniformly via hashing in multithreaded evnironments

Tags: java, multithreading, math, hash, concurrency

I've implemented a java code to execute incoming tasks (as `Runnable`) with n Threads based on their hashCode module `nThreads`. The work should spread, ideally - uniformly, among those threads.
Specifically, we have a `dispatchId` as a string for each Task.

Here is this java code snippet:

```
int nThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(); // Number of threads
Worker[] workers = new Worker[nThreads]; // Those threads, Worker is just a thread class that can run incoming tasks
...
Worker getWorker(String dispatchId) { // Get a thread for this Task
    return workers[(dispatchId.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % nThreads];
}
```

**Important:** In most cases a dispatchId is:

```
String dispatchId = 'SomePrefix' + counter.next()
```

But, I have a concern that modulo division by nThreads is not a good choice, because nThreads should be a prime number for a more uniform distribution of dispatId keys.

Are there any other options on how to spread the work better?

**Update 1:**

Each Worker has a queue:
`Queue<RunnableWrapper> tasks = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();`

The worker gets tasks from it and executes them. Tasks can be added to this queue from other threads.

**Update 2:**

Tasks with the same `dispatchId` can come in multiple times, therefore we need to find their thread by `dispatchId`.

Most importantly, each Worker thread must process its incoming tasks sequentially. Hence, there is data structure Queue in the update 1 above.

**Update 3:**
Also, some threads can be busy, while others are free. Thus, we need to somehow decouple Queues from Threads, but maintain the FIFO order for the same `dispatchId` for tasks execution.

**Solution:**
I've implemented Ben Manes' idea (his answer below), the code can be found [here](https://github.com/vibneiro/dispatching).

Comment: It has nothing to do with nThreads being prime or not!

Comment: May be you need to use `ThreadPoolExecutor`. Examine [Thread Pools](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html) and [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html).

Comment: @Lrrr Not true.
    If you use a power of 2 for table_length, finding (hashCode(key) % 2^n ) is as simple and quick as (hashCode(key) & (2^n -1)). But if your function to calculate hashCode for a given key isn't good, you will definitely suffer from clustering of many keys in a few hash buckets.
    But if you use prime numbers for table_length, hashCodes calculated could map into the different hash buckets even if you have a slightly stupid hashCode function.

Comment: Do you have data on how the tasks are distributed among workers?

Comment: @infgeoax yes, it is a counter. e.g. String dispatchId = 'ModuleName' + counter.next(). I'll update the question.

Comment: Why do you not just use random integer number in interval `[0, workers.length)`?

Comment: @yozh Please give more details on the idea, better to give proof why it is more uniform

Comment: Does a worker maintain a data structure for pending jobs?

Comment: @vibneiro I mean returning `workers[rnd.nextInt(workers.length)]` where `rnd` is instance of [Random](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html). Do you have to use `hashCode` of a task for selection?

Comment: @christopher Yes, each worker is a thread that has: private Queue<RunnableWrapper> tasks = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<RunnableWrapper>(); the worker gets tasks from it and executes them. tasks can be added to this queue from different other threads. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: @yozh Yes, I will need to find a thread by this hashCode later.

Comment: @alex2410 Thanks, i was not quite clear. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you need FIFO ordering per dispatch id, so the ideal would be to have dispatch queues as the abstraction. That would explain your concern about hashing as not providing uniform distribution, as some dispatch queues may be more active than others and unfairly balanced among workers. By separating the queue from the worker, you retain FIFO semantics and evenly spread out the work.

An inactive library that provides this abstraction is [HawtDispatch](https://github.com/fusesource/hawtdispatch). It is Java 6 compatible.

A very simple Java 8 approach is to use [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) as a queuing mechanism, [ConcurrentHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) for registration, and an Executor (e.g. [ForkJoinPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html)) for computing. See [EventDispatcher](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/blob/master/jcache/src/main/java/com/github/benmanes/caffeine/jcache/event/EventDispatcher.java) for an implementation of this idea, where registration is explicit. If your dispatchers are more dynamic then you may need to periodically prune the map. The basic idea is as follows.

```
ConcurrentMap<String, CompletableFuture<Void>> dispatchQueues = ...

public CompletableFuture<Void> dispatch(String queueName, Runnable task) {
  return dispatchQueues.compute(queueName, (k, queue) -> {
    return (queue == null)
        ? CompletableFuture.runAsync(task)
        : queue.thenRunAsync(task);
  });
}
```

**Update (JDK7)**

A backport of the above idea would be translated with Guava into something like,

```
ListeningExecutorService executor = ...
Striped<Lock> locks = Striped.lock(256);
ConcurrentMap<String, ListenableFuture<?>> dispatchQueues = ...

public ListenableFuture<?> dispatch(String queueName, final Runnable task) {
  Lock lock = locks.get(queueName);
  lock.lock();
  try {
    ListenableFuture<?> future = dispatchQueues.get(queueName);
    if (future == null) {
      future = executor.submit(task);
    } else {
      final SettableFuture<Void> next = SettableFuture.create();
      future.addListener(new Runnable() {
        try {
          task.run();
        } finally {
          next.set(null);
        }
      }, executor);
      future = next;
    }
    dispatchQueues.put(queueName, future);
  } finally {
    lock.unlock();
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right - this causes unfair thread-load. Your approach is quite interesting. Thanks for the links! Can I do this in java 7?

Comment: @vibneiro Updated with an untested backport

Comment: @Ben Manes, what about OutOfMemory? map will grow only. I am interested in JDK 8 approach

Comment: @gstackoverflow Use a weak valued [cache](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Eviction#reference-based) which will discard an entry when the future has completed.

Comment: I think @IvanVoroshilin wrote a blog on this?

Comment: Or you could add a `whenComplete` that uses `remove(k, v)` to remove iff the completed future is the value.

Comment: @Ben Manes 1. I could use only jdk classes and 2. Could you clarify the phrase. What mean **iff the completed future is the value** ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow "if and only if". Before returning the `future`, add a `whenComplete` that executes `dispatchQueues.remove(queueName, future)` to remove the future if no other tasks have been chained (last is in the map). You may also need to replace `thenRunAsync` with a `whenComplete` if you want tasks to run even if predecessor failed.

Comment: @Ben Manes, sorry for stupid question, I haven't encountered with completable future before - how to check that no other task chained ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153172/discussion-between-ben-manes-and-gstackoverflow).