# Large number of single threaded task queues

Tags: java, concurrency, redis, distributed, task-queue

At our company we have a server which is distributed into few instances. Server handles users requests. Requests from different users can be processed in parallel. Requests from same users should be executed strongly sequentionally. But they can arrive to different instances due to balancing. Currently we use Redis-based distributed locks but this is error-prone and requires more work around concurrency than business logic.

What I want is something like this (more like a concept):

- Distinct queue for each user
- Queue is named after user id
- Each requests identified by request id
- Imagine two requests from the same user arriving at two different instances concurrently:

  1. Each instance put their request id into this user queue.
  2. Additionaly, they both store their request ids locally.
  3. Then some broker takes request id from the top of "some_user_queue" and moves it into "some_user_queue_processing"
  4. Both instances listen for "some_user_queue_processing". They peek into it and see if this is request id they stored locally. If yes, then do processing. If not, then ignore and wait.
  5. When work is done server deletes this id from "some_user_queue_processing".
  6. Then step 3 again.

And all of this happens concurrently for a lot (thousands of them) of different users (and their queues).

Now, I know this sounds a lot like actors, but:

1. We need solution requiring as small changes as possible to make fast transition from locks. Akka will force us to rewrite almost everything from scratch.
2. We need production ready solution. Quasar sounds good, but is not production ready yet (more correctly, their Galaxy cluster).
3. Tops at my work are very conservative, they simply don't want another dependency which we'll need to support. But we already use Redis (for distributed locks), so I thought maybe it could help with this too.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you could evaluate Hazelcas's support for distributed locks, see http://hazelcast.org/#lock .

Comment: Assuming sticky sessions, its simple to write a [dispatch queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889885/java-divide-incoming-work-uniformly-via-hashing-in-multithreaded-evnironments/29893297#29893297) in Java 8.

Comment: Can you tell me if my answer is what you need actually?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution that matches the description of your problem is [Redis Cluster](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec).

Basically, the cluster solves your concurrency problem, in the following way:

Two (or more) requests from the same user, will **always** go to the same instance, assuming that you use the user-id as a key and the request as a value. The value must be actually a [list](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) of requests. When you receive one, you will append it to that list. In other words, that is your queue of requests (a single one for every user).

That matching is being possible by the design of the cluster implementation. It is based on a range of hash-slots spread over all the instances.

When a *set* command is executed, the cluster performs a hashing operation, which results in a value (the hash-slot that we are going to write on), which is located on a specific instance. The cluster finds the instance that contains the right range, and then performs the writing procedure.

Also, when a *get* is performed, the cluster does the same procedure: it finds the instance that contains the key, and then it gets the value.

The transition from locks is very easy to perform because you only need to have the instances ready (with the cluster-enabled directive set on "yes") and then to run the cluster-create command from redis-trib.rb script.

I've worked last summer with the cluster in a production environment and it behaved very well.