# Executor for grouped by key messages

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have sequential messages. Each message has a key (in my case I use locale as a key). I need some type of executor which allow me put this messages in different queues by the key and handle queues in parallel thread.
Does java have something for my case? Or maybe google guava does?
Something like that:

```
Executor<K, T> {
  Map<K, LinkedList<T>> groupedTasks;

  void submit(K key, T task);
}
```

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889885/java-divide-incoming-work-uniformly-via-hashing-in-multithreaded-evnironments/29893297#29893297) using futures to create independent execution chains.

Comment: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889885/java-divide-incoming-work-uniformly-via-hashing-in-multithreaded-evnironments/29893297#29893297) provided by Ben Manes is worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try this https://github.com/jano7/executor

From the description:

> This small library provides an optimized solution to a problem where tasks for a particular key need to be processed sequentially as they arrive. This kind of problem can be solved by a SingleThreadExecutor, however it is not efficient. The issue is that the tasks for unrelated keys are not being processed in parallel. Instead, they are put into a queue common to all keys and wait for the single thread to execute them. This library allows them to be executed concurrently. Moreover, this library works well in a situation where all the possible keys and their number is not known upfront.