# How to write correctness test for concurrent class?(that 2 actions is not executed in parallel )

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, concurrency

I've got task to write my custom executor service.

It should work almost as usual but 2 tasks with same key(field of task) should not be executed in parallel. I've wrote the code and I am sure that it should work correct.

But I need to write test. I haven't encountered the with test like this.

I could not google something useful about this.

Please, share your experience.

### P.S.

I have executor with following interface:

```
  class TaskExecutor {
        void submit(Task task){
           ...
        }
    }


class Task implements Runnable{
     String key;
     public void run(){...}
     ...
}
```

and somewhere

```
taskExecutor.execute(new MyTask() {                              

                            @Override
                            public String getKey() {
                                return "key1"
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void run() {...}
                  );
```

Comment: Could you share a [MCVE]?

Comment: @Mureinik Is it enough?

Comment: Where's the synchronized part?

Comment: @Mureinik Inside executor. To be more precise inside PoolThread implementation . It is implementaion details from my point of view. My question about testing of correctness if I have described interface

Comment: Try flooding your executor with **big** number of tasks with same key, each of which validates that some static atomic boolean is not `true`, then immediately gets a hold of it, sleeps for a while, then releases. If all tasks execute sequentially as you'd expect, then when each of the tasks executes, the boolean should always have `false` in it, which is what you should validate.

Comment: I would use [Awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) with custom tasks that check some conditions. Fyi, using `ConcurrentHashMap` and `CompletableFuture` you can implement your executor in a few LOC.

Comment: @Ben Manes Can you clarify what does mean LOC ?

Comment: Lines of Code. You can use a weak valued cache and futures to create a [keyed executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889885/java-divide-incoming-work-uniformly-via-hashing-in-multithreaded-evnironments/29893297#29893297) with very little effort.

Answer (score 0):

I would first test that if the threads run sequentially everything is correct. So build a test with a Single Threaded Executor Service and check that it handles the threads correctly. Here you can also test corner cases in your algorithm if any.

Then test what happens when the threads are running in parallel. I do not think that this is possible without tool support. I see two tools which could help you here:

1. [jcstress](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/CodeTools/jcstress) This is an open source tool developed as part of OpenJDK. It allows you to run your tests multiple times making sure that you catch errors which only happens at specific thread interleaving. You probably can not test your complete executor service using this tool. But you should be able to test the algorithm which you use to make sure that a task is not scheduled multiple times.
2. [vmlens](http://vmlens.com) Disclaimer: I develop this tool. vmlens is a commercial tool but you can, of course, download a trial version. It traces your application and can detect race condition in the execution trace.

As the last point, I want to give you an example of a race condition which you can not detect without one of those tools:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
String sc = stringCache;
if (sc == null)
 stringCache = sc = layoutChars(true);
return sc;
}
/**
* Used to store the canonical string representation, if computed.
*/
private transient String stringCache;
```

As you see this method is not thread safe. The instance variable stringCache is read and written without being volatile or synchronization. If you run this with jcstress on an AMD compatible Processor you will see the following NullPointer Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.lang.String.equals(String.java:982)
```

You probably will not see such an error on an Intel processor since 
 Intel processors do not reorder statements. By the way, this is the toString method from java.­math.­BigDecimal.

Comment: I am not sure that you understood me correct. What does mean 1 ?

Comment: I was too fast :-) Hope this answer is better