# Can this lock pool implementation be improved?

Tags: java, concurrency, java-11

I've written this Spring event listener that handles requests to update tasks (although my question really has nothing to do with Spring). I want to ensure that we never concurrently process requests to update the same task. To achieve this, I maintain a `Map` of locks. If the map contains an entry whose key is a task's ID, and whose value is a locked lock, this means that the task with this ID is currently being updated, and any attempt to update it will have to wait for the lock to be released.

```
@Component
public class TaskUpdateEventListener {

    private final ConcurrentMap<UUID, Lock> taskLocks = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @TransactionalEventListener
    @Async
    public void onTaskUpdate(TaskUpdateEvent taskUpdateEvent) {
        var taskId = taskUpdateEvent.getTaskId();
        var taskLock = taskLocks.computeIfAbsent(taskId, taskIdKey -> new ReentrantLock());
        taskLock.lock();

        try {
            updateTask(taskId);
        } finally {
            // Notice that we never remove locks from the Map
            taskLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private void updateTask(UUID taskId) {
        // implementation omitted
    }
}
```

One thing I don't like about this implementation is that locks never get removed from `taskLocks`. I suspect there must be a way to ensure that requests to update the same task are processed sequentially without maintaining a pool of locks e.g. using [lock conditions](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/locks-concurrent/condition/java-util-concurrent-locks-condition-example/).

Comment: If this code works, perhaps try asking at [codereview.se].

Comment: You can use a weak valued cache to automatically discard entries when there are no strong references to the lock (e.g. see Guava `Striped` or Caffeine cache). Per your musing about a higher-level construct, you might use a [dispatch queue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29893297/19450) to abstract away the lock and schedule the work on a thread pool.