# Process data in a strict order using completable futures

Tags: java, asynchronous, guava, java.util.concurrent, completable-future

I have a program where I need to process documents in a strict order. For different documents, the order isn't important, but for multiple updates to the **same document**, the order is vital.

I use a ConcurrentHashMap<documentId, ReentrantLock> to lock documents. Each document has a unique id, when we get updates to the same document they will be for the same id.

Our tps is quite high, so we need to be able to process these documents quickly.

One approach that we have thought about is the following:

```
void process(doc) {
    String id = doc.getId();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {getLock();}, executor)
    .thenRunAsync(() -> { doSomeWork();}, executor)
    .whenComplete((ignored, err) -> {
        removeFromLockMap(id);
        handleErrors(err);
    }, executor).join()
```

The issue with this approach, is that the thread (from the executor) which gets the lock is not always the same thread which attempts to unlock the lock.

One approach is to use an array of SingleThreadPool executors and use guava's Iterators.cycle() to create a ring-like iterator to get a new executor for each call to process. That way all the async calls in a single process call will run on the same thread.

However, this seems rather hacky to me, and will not scale. We might need 1000 executors in order to process our data, and sometimes it might spike to 1500 executors.

I do know that if a SingleThreaded executor is already executing a job, the next job will go to a queue and wait for the previous job. However, this will violate our latency SLA.

Any suggestion on how we can achieve our SLA while still maintaining our ordering requirements?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand it completely.  If the input for one update _depends_ on the output of previous one, how could you do the updates in parallel..? Shouldn't you be doing the updates (*for any one given document*) in a blocking loop?

Comment: @Tintin, Perhaps a good analogy would be processing emails. I do not want to process a reply to an email before I process the original email. What is in the original email is not import to processing the reply (although it would be for the reader!), but I don't want the original to appear as if it is a reply to the actual apply. Does that help?

Comment: This sounds similar to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29889885/java-divide-incoming-work-uniformly-via-hashing-in-multithreaded-evnironments/29893297#29893297). In that scheme, you can easily remove the mapping via weak references. You might be able to adapt Guava's `ExecutionSequencer` or `MoreExecutors.newSequentialExecutor` for similar behavior. But I find the `CompletableFuture` approach simplest and evicting when the last in work item completes is straightforward.

Comment: @BenManes Want to make that an answer? I really appreciate your help here.

Comment: You obviously have a use case for a [*semaphore* with a single permit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#release():~:text=A%20semaphore%20initialized%20to%20one,no%20notion%20of%20ownership%29.), rather than a lock: “*When used in this way, the binary semaphore has the property (unlike many Lock implementations), that the "lock" can be released by a thread other than the owner (as semaphores have no notion of ownership).*”